# How to use azure vault secret in yaml kubernetes registery?

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, yaml, azure-aks

I am using a Yaml file to deploy my images in private azure. As I need to push my Yaml to my git repository, I don't want the Yaml file includes the image registry credentials. So I created a secret Azure vault and mapped it in a volume. But I can't find any option for this.

```
properties:
  containers:
  - name: app
    properties:
      image: myreg.azurecr.io/my-app:latest
      .
      .
      .
      volumeMounts:
      - name: secrets
        mountPath: /mnt/secrets
  volumes:
  - name: secrets
    secret:
      secretName: aaa
      vaultName: bbb
      objectType: ccc
  imageRegistryCredentials:
    - server: myreg.azurecr.io
      secret:
        name: my-secret-name
        type: secret
```

I get this error:

> (InvalidRequestContent) The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'secret' on object of type 'ImageRegistryCredential'.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below steps:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

1. Create a docker-registry secret
   kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=acrname.azurecr.io --docker-username=username--docker-password=pwd
2. Sample YAML file:

apiVersion: v1

kind: Pod

metadata:

name: private-reg

spec:

containers:

- name: private-reg-container

  image: acrname.azurecr.io/image:latest

imagePullSecrets:

- name: regcred